# Harddrive errors, likely cause?

Tags: hard-drive, read-only, sata

Today while trying to install a program with wine, the whole system suddenly became read only and pretty much everything stopped working. After reboot things worked, but I found the following errors with dmesg:

```
[  475.903404] ata2.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  475.903405] ata2.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[  475.903408] ata2: hard resetting link
[  476.223280] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[  476.348052] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
[  476.363215] ata2: EH complete
[  900.530254] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1800000 SErr 0x0 action 0x6
[  900.530258] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[  900.530262] ata2.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  900.530266] ata2.00: cmd 60/00:c0:00:89:33/01:00:21:00:00/40 tag 24 ncq 131072 in
[  900.530266]          res 41/84:00:02:89:33/00:01:21:00:00/00 Emask 0x410 (ATA bus error) <F>
[  900.530269] ata2.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  900.530270] ata2.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[  900.530273] ata2: hard resetting link
[  900.858024] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[  901.030118] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
[  901.045986] ata2: EH complete
```

The smartctl output:

```
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-4.4.1-040401-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Laptop SSHD
Device Model:     ST500LM000-SSHD-8GB
Serial Number:    W760MRLZ
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0783c2056
Firmware Version: LVD3
User Capacity:    500.107.862.016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Feb 14 02:46:49 2016 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  139) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  99) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x1081) SCT Status supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   117   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       165299784
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   099   098   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       733
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   074   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       25966261
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       4378
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       685
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   058   051   045    Old_age   Always       -       42 (Min/Max 39/44)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       28
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1009
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   042   049   000    Old_age   Always       -       42 (0 13 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      4378         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

I have seen that similar errors could indicate a faulty sata wire. Is there anything I can do or check for?

Answer (score 0):

If you think the SATA cable is faulty, replace it with a known-good one.  If errors persist, it's not the cable.

Comment: The problem is that I can't touch the hardware because of the warranty. So I really need to make sure there is a hardware problem before I send it to warranty repair, which takes forever. Howe can I test for possible software causes? or is this definitely a hardware issue?

Comment: If you are not allowed to troubleshoot because of the warranty, then you need to contact the vendor and work with them to create a return authorization and restore from your last known-good backup when you receive the replacement hardware.